# Why my timer doesn't want to fire at the specified interval?

Tags: swift, timer

I have these two functions in my class:

```
func setTimer () {
    alertEndTimer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(hideAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
    print ("NOW: \(now)") 
    print ("FIRE DATE: \(alertEndTimer!.fireDate)");
}

@IBAction func hideAlert () {
    doSomething();
}
```

The result of the console is like this:

```
NOW: 2017-03-01 03:32:36 +0000
FIRE DATE: 2017-03-01 03:32:46 +0000
```

I then put a break point on `doSomething();`. But after waiting for like 1 minute, the break point is not called at all. I also have checked whether the timer `isValid()`, and it returns true. So why doesn't my function get called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer#1667642):

> Use the `init(timeInterval:invocation:repeats:)` or `init(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)` class method to create the timer object without scheduling it on a run loop. **(After creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling the `add(_:forMode:)` method of the corresponding `RunLoop` object.)**

That is you need to call

```
RunLoop.current.add(alertEndTimer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
```

in order to start the timer.

---

You could create the timer using the [`scheduledTimer` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer) to start it automatically.

```
alertEndTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, 
                                     target: self, 
                                     selector: #selector(hideAlert),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: false)
```

Comment: Okay, I have used `scheduledTimer()` in several parts of my app, but the `scheduledTimer()` doesn't have `fireAt:`. so that's why sometimes I revert to use `init()`, and that's why sometimes the timer looks working, and sometimes not. Ok, now everything is working. I never heard about `RunLoop`, I thought it's something like a swift transparent internal thread to run the Timer, and lookup about `RunLoop` seems yield lots of results. Thanks.